# How to prevent images from being resized in game maker?

Tags: sprites, game-maker, image

This warning appeared in the compilation menu of my game.

[image]

The images were rescaled in half. I understand that this happened because they had very large dimensions.

It turns out that the images, although they have a large size (pixels), are very light, because they are composed for the most part by simple traces in addition to having the transparent background.

Below, one of the images:

[image]

You see, it is very light.

It turns out that in the game it stops being clear.

[image]

How do I solve my problem? Using smaller images is out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your image is bigger than texture pages size then GMS resizes the image.

Don't see how small your PNGs are. They will be unpacked when loaded into memory. Each pixel will eat 4 bytes (32 bits). So 2446×1008 requires more than 9 MB. Moreover, some videocards can work only with textures which size is a power of two. It means that 2446×1008 actually will be 4096×1024 (empty area will be added). And [Texture pages](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/001_advanced%20use/more%20about%20backgrounds/texture%20pages.html) is thing which allows to optimize it (but for very big images it may work inefficient in some cases).

Change [texture pages size](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/001_advanced%20use/global%20game%20settings/windows%20tab.html) from 2048*2048 (default value) to 4096*4096.
But keep in mind that then your game may not work on some “old” hardware. Also you can split your each big image into two smaller. Like 2446×1008 → 2048×1008 + 398×1008

[image]

But when I see your images I don't see any reason to do it as big images. It's very inefficient. I would prefer draw it using that small blocks.